# Using same object to write wide char and char to write to the same file

Tags: c++, c, stream, fstream

I have C code that I am trying to convert to C++. To summarize a snippet of the code in C is as follows:

```
    FILE *fp = fopen("temp.bin", "wb");
    wchar_t* wide_word = _T("wide char");
    char* word = "char";
    fwprintf(fp, _T("%s"), wide_word);
    fprintf(fp, "%s", word);
```

The advantage in the C case being we can continue using the same fp pointer to print both char and wide char by simple passing the pointer. Can we achieve the same in C++ without needing to initialize to objects `ofstream` and `wofstream` to write to the same file and get exact same output as the above C implementation?

I tried the following in C++ (amongst many other things)

```
    auto os = std::ofstream("temp_cpp.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
    wchar_t* wide_word = _T("wide char");
    char* word = "char";
    std::wstring st(wide_word);
    std::string str(st.begin(),st.end());
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(str.c_str()), sizeof(str));
    os.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(word), sizeof(word));
```

Comment: No, for the same reason the code snippet requires you to use both `fprintf()` and `fwprintf()`.

Comment: `sizeof(str)` remember that `sizeof()` is a compile time constant in `c++`

Comment: You are usually supposed to create files of same definite encoding or support proper data serialization. You could use some hackish trick with `reinterpret_cast`, but how are you going to read the data afterwards?

Comment: The data is being used into a `wstring` variable.

Comment: You can't do what you present in C, either, not and have a well-defined result.  C streams are either byte-oriented or wide-oriented, depending on the nature of the first I/O function to be used on them, and you must not ("shall not", per the Standard) apply wide functions to byte-oriented streams or vise versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the same `write` function to either write the ANSI bytes or wide char bytes to the file. There are some mistakes in the code. `sizeof(str)` will return the size of the `std::string` object, not the length of the string and `sizeof(word)` will return the size of a pointer, again not the length of the string (although you might be lucky with this one on 32-bit systems where the size of the pointer matches your string length). Further, you are writing ANSI chars two times rather than first writing wide chars and then ANSI chars as you have probably intended following your `fprintf` example. What you meant to write there was probably:

```
auto os = std::ofstream("temp_cpp.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
const wchar_t* wide_word = L"wide char";
const char* word = "char";
std::wstring st(wide_word);
std::string str(st.begin(), st.end());
os.write((const char*)(st.c_str()), st.length() * sizeof(wchar_t));
os.write(word, strlen(word));
```

This should yield the same file content as your `fprintf` example (but it is not guaranteed as it may depend on `setLocale`). Or, without the use of `std::wstring`:

```
auto os = std::ofstream("temp_cpp.bin", std::ios::binary | std::ios::out);
const wchar_t* wide_word = L"wide char";
const char* word = "char";
os.write((const char*)wide_word, wcslen(wide_word) * sizeof(wchar_t));
os.write(word, strlen(word));
```

Whether it is advisable to write different text encodings into the same file is another question.

Comment: Yes, you can *write the bytes of the `wchar_t` data*, but that does not necessarily produce the same effect as writing a wide string via wide-oriented I/O functions / objects.  The internal representation is not necessarily the same as the external one, and the wide I/O functions perform any needed translation.

Comment: Thank you; I have updated the answer. You would need to read the bytes back in the same way as you have written them. I believe the intent was to write into the same stream, not necessarily to produce the same output as `fwprintf`.